# org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Unknown property used in expression

Tags: camunda

I am trying to use an delegate expression on a Service Task but throws this error “org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Unknown property used in expression ${abcService.reminderEmailCheck(execution)}. Cause Cannot resolve identifier ‘abcService’”

We tried with enabling "Asynchronous Before" and "Exclusive" settings on the timer but didn't work.
We put a 5 sec timer after the "Start 2 day Reminder" Timer but still did not work.
We tried with the combination of approach#1 and #2 but still did not work.

The timer "Start 2 Day Reminder" fails at least 80-90% of the times. The delegate "abcService" is being referred at many places in the process but it doesn't fail anywhere else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switch to "expression" when you want to enter the full "bean.method(arg)". If you want to use a delegateExpression, implement "JavaDelegate" and just reference the bean: `#{abcService}`.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for responding on my question. We are following the same (the expression) in the actual project. The screenshot is just a near replica of that.